# Two columns with dates (one any day of week, another one WEEK ENDING DATE (SATURDAY) BASED ON 1st column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such a situation.
I need to have 2 columns 1) Is just pull data from a table (just as it is) r.[RCLDTE] (Day of week)
and 2 column) I need to basically look at the first column and make it Saturday of that week.

```
SELECT r.[RCLDTE] AS 'Day of Week'
,r.[RCLDTE] AS 'Week Ending Day (Saturday)'
```

Before what I was doing at similar projects I just used this code and added to WHERE statement.

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8), r.[RCLDTE] ))  = cast(DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())*-1, GETDATE()) as date)
```

This code was changing the dates column to Saturday.

However, here I have a different situation. I need 2 columns 1) as it is and 2) where dates will be Saturdays of the week from r.[RCLDTE] column , as a result from the way how I understand I cannot use WHERE statement because it will affect both columns.

Does someone know how I can leave 1st column as it is and 2nd a column of Saturday.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. In your `SELECT` you just reference 1 column, `r.[RCLDTE]`, so if it date is a Saturday, it will be a Saturday in *both* columns. If it isn't a Saturday, it won't be in both columns. SQL Server doesn't support quantum values, where it can have multiple values at the same time.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid issues when someone [changes either `DATEFIRST` or `LANGUAGE` settings](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=227d2cf6efbeed16240936b9f45701aa), you can use this. Also, given that you are storing dates in a `numeric` column for some reason (you really should provide feedback to whoever owns the system so they can fix it), we have to first try to convert those values to a date (they may not all be valid, which is one of the problems with using the wrong data type):

```
;WITH t AS 
(
  SELECT *, ProperDate = CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(char(8), RCLDTE)) = 1
    THEN CONVERT(date, CONVERT(char(8), RCLDTE)) END
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT [Language] = @@language, [Datefirst] = @@datefirst,
       RCLDTE = CASE WHEN ProperDate IS NULL THEN RCLDTE END, 
       [Day of Week] = ProperDate,
       [Saturday] = DATEADD
       (
         DAY, 
         6 - ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ProperDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7), 
         ProperDate
       )
FROM t;
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2bad19f516b9488c6b8fea8148703bd9) that also demonstrates the handling of garbage data and a version of SQL Server so old that `TRY_CONVERT()` didn't exist yet (at least 12 years ago).

Comment: thank you very much. I am sure it works, but I get an error for some reason namely "' Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.'"

Comment: Thank you. There is another issue now. I received an error: ''TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.' (I use SSMS)

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select 
   r.RCLDTE AS 'Day of Week'
   , dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(weekday, r.RCLDTE) , r.RCLDTE)
from tablename r
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecb815199544b7c4482912b9c74047f5)*

Comment: This works in default us_english and datefirst 7 settings, but [fails if you change either of those](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=227d2cf6efbeed16240936b9f45701aa).

Comment: @AaronBertrand true

Comment: Thank you. It gives me 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.' error. This column r.RCLDTE is of NUMERIC format. Do you know how I can adjust this dateadd part to the  data type format ?

Comment: @Stephansko what's the datatype of rcldate then? provide sample data then

Comment: @Stephansko (1) why are you storing a date in a numeric column? (2) this is why it is useful to include your table definition and some sample data and desired results in the question (see https://sqlblog.org/ask)

Comment: @eshirvana r.RCLDTE is of NUMERIC. The example is '20211109'. In the documentations of the table that I use i saw information this column is NUMERIC. If I run Eshirvana query i get ' Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.'

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am not sure how to respond to your question. I build reports but I don't assign the original format of columns. I use SSMS, I checked the documentation for this table and found out that this column is of NUMERIC format. I am not sure what I can add to it.